# How does PostgreSQL compute the cost for index scan?

Tags: postgresql, index

Consider the following plan:

```
Index Scan using foo_c1_idx1 on foo  (cost=0.00..8.38 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (c1 = 500)
  Buffers: shared hit=4
Total runtime: 0.036 ms
```

As we can see, the cost to get all rows is `8.38`. On my system

```
SELECT current_setting('random_page_cost');
```

return `4`.

So, as long as the index scan `includes` 2 random page reading (The first one is to read an index, and the second one to read the actual table), it's not clear what the `0.38` means in the plan?

Could you explain how it's computed?

Comment: `the second one to read the actual table` - where? There's nothing in PLAN about reading the "actual table".

Comment: @user4419802 So why do we need two random page accesses?

Comment: @user4419802 I mean, by reading the index we get the page the result is contained in. After this we need to read that page (random access)

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMkU=1wFK=4eDfpOHhygg49FgRR+H9Drw1ae1TP=v+uqTZ4Y+g@mail.gmail.com and http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/27581.1352393137@sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot that in PSQL `Index scan` is actually 'index read + access by rowid'. Then 0.38 is additional "CPU cost".

Comment: @user4419802 Just to make sure, what sql-server did you mean while asking...?

Comment: Well, I used to think in Oracle terms: reading "actual table" (i.e. heap data) is specifically marked as "TABLE ACCESS BY ROWID". So simply "INDEX" without any "TABLE ACCESS" is like "Index only scan" in postgres.